# Qt4, QProcess, R: garbage in standard output with longer lines

Tags: r, qt4, qprocess

I'm working on a yet another one GUI-frontend for R (mainly to study Qt4 on a more or less relevant material), and I've stumbled upon an unusual behavior of components involved.
If I try to write a line of 76 characters or longer to R's stdin via QProcess, the output (echo of the command) returns with garbage inclusions and with parts of the line being repeated. For example:

```
freq.some <- recode(freq, "'some' = 'no'; 'all or most' = 'yes'; else = NA");
```

is echoed as

```
freq.some <- recode(freq, "'some' = 'no'; 'all or most' = 'yes'; else = NA"
< "'some' = 'no'; 'all or most' = 'yes'; else = 
NA")                         ;
```

I tried working with the output right on the QByteArray level, but the anomaly is already there.

My Qt version is 4.6.3, R v. 2.11.1, Debian Squeeze. Relevant code snippets follow:

This is how I start R's process:

```
arrr = new QProcess(this);
QString program = "R --interactive --no-readline";
arrr->start(program, QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
```

This is how I write the command to R's process:

```
QString cmd = ui->lineEdit->displayText();
QString tmp = cmd + "\n";
arrr->write(tmp.toUtf8().data());
```

This is how I read the output of the process:

```
QByteArray output;
QTextStream *ts = new QTextStream(&output);
output = arrr->readAllStandardOutput();
QString r_output = ts->readAll();
```

Reading from the process occurs upon readyRead() signal.

I apologize beforehand if my question does not conform to the accepted standards of this site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that in the long run you may find piping into R and reading the standard output to be rather troublesome.  I suggest a few alternatives you could look into:

- [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve) provides a headless R server you connect to via tcp/ip; a sample C++ client exists
- Direct R embedding as per the `Writing R Extensions' manual (but you'd drop down to a lot of fairly bare-metal C code)
- [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) wraps the R API for embedding in much higher abstraction C++ using the sibbling package [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html).  Plus, I recently added a detailed example of how to do that from [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) which is now in SVN (but not yet on CRAN); there is also a 
  [detailed blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25#rinside_and_qt) about it.

Comment: (1) I probably should mention that before I upgraded from Lenny to Squeeze, this problem did not arise. (2) I tried to make a simple and crossplatform solution. I fear that requiring a standalone server or using an extra library may make that goal complicated or unreachable.

Comment: (1) If you can boil it down to a reproducible example (preferable not requiring Qt) then R-devel would certainly like to hear it.  (2) Sure, you need to trade off flexibility and reliability. You have none of the latter here.  Rcpp is in Debian (maintained by me) and I could easily add RInside (there hasn't been demand yet) and at that point it is "all stock Debian" so who cares if another shared library is loaded?  It's not that R itself is leightweight...

Comment: (1) How can I possibly boil down a Qt app to a non-Qt example? R in itself works just fine as a console application. It is my understanding that the issue lies within Qt framework. All my application is meant to do is writing to and reading from an R process and be a "pretty" layer above (in particular, allowing to edit R's output in chunks to generate a neat report in place). (2) "Crossplatfrom" means exactly that a considerable share of the target audience does not use neither specifically Debian, nor Linux in general.

Comment: (1) You can pipe into R using echo; and receive the answer with sed/perl/python/...  Remember, it is *you* aiming to demonstrate a bug in R. Please do so in a way that makes it easy to replicate the bug. (2) Life is full of tradeoffs.

Comment: (1) Yes, I am trying to investigate the issue further. As of now, I can say that if I use qprocess to start windows version of R using wine, the output is processed as it should be. I will try piping now to see if it's R or Qt. (2) Truly, it is, but if I won't be able to run the app under windows, there's no value in it at all. Also, I don't have MS Windows myself, so my only hope in providing crossplatform compatibility is sticking with Qt and its crossplatform-safe structures.

Comment: If I understood you fully, this: echo "freq.some <- recode(freq, \"'some' = 'no'; 'all or most' = 'yes'; else = NA\");" | R --vanilla | sed 's/freq/FREQ/' | grep FREQ — should be a valid test. If so, it does not show the behavior in question, the output is: > FREQ.some <- recode(freq, "'some' = 'no'; 'all or most' = 'yes'; else = NA"); I guess I'll make a minimal qt application next this evening to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I made a minimal code sample, which shows the described behavior: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/971118/qrgui.tar.bz2 Also, somehow the behavior differs when the app is run from the command prompt from running is by (e.g.) double-clicking in file manager: in the first case, there is less distortion (mostly whitespaces).